# Better structure to watch window level DOM events in Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

In a CompositeView, I implemented infinite scrolling like this

```
List.Foo extends Marionette.CompositeView

  initialize: (collection) ->
    @page = 1
    $(window).on('scroll', @loadMore)

  loadMore: =>
    if _nearBottom
      @page++
      App.vent.trigger('list:foo:near_bottom', @page)

  _nearBottom =>
    $(window).scrollTop > $(document).height - $(window.height) - 200

# Then I have the controller to process the event "list:foo:near_bottom", 
# to ask for adding one more page of data in collection.
```

The code basically works as expected. But I can't find it satisfactory as I think this ComposteView watches some DOM events outside of its scope, aka, the window level DOM events.

I thought to use a layout to watch such events and broadcast it, but my top level layout seems still not broad enough to cover window/document :)

My question is, what would be a better structure to watch these kinds of window/document level DOM event in Marionette? Thanks!

Comment: I've struggled with this question and I think it's one of those 'non-best-practice' things that you just have to deal with. By definition, a Backbone view will always be at a lower level than 'window' and also by definition, scroll events will often need to be captured at the 'window' level.  That means that it's often impossible to have the event happen in the scope of a view.  Just remember to cleanup your listeners when you close the view.

Comment: @TNguyen, thanks a lot for your nice opinion! I also have some new understandingd similar to yours but have some difference, so I posted my own answer. Please check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has not been answered for a long time, and I changed implementation in that project so I didn't touch it.

Nguyen's comment provided very nice point and reminds me to review this question.

I also have new understanding similar to Nguyen's point.

Something has to be global, we can't avoid it.

These things include but not limited to:

- Route
- Page scroll
- Page load
- Window resize
- Global key stroke
- ...

Backbone has Routes to take care of routing events. The others things are not so important and so popular but they still need to be treated similar to routing.

A better approach would be, in my opinion: Watching the global DOM events at global level, send App event which don't care whoever may be interested in it.

If I re-do this feature, I will do something like this(pseudo code)

```
# App
App.on "initialize:after", ->
  @startHistory()
  @navigate('somePath', trigger: true) # Normal steps
  App.module('WindowWatcher').start()

# WindowWatcher module
ExampleProject.module "WindowWatcher", (WindowWatcher, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  class Watcher
    constructor: ->
      @watchPageScroll

    watchPageScroll: ->
      $(window).on('scroll', @_checkScroll)

    _checkScroll: ->
      if @_nearBottom:
        App.vent.trigger(scroll:bottom)

    _nearBottom:
      $(window).scrollTop > $(document).height - $(window.height) - 200

  WindowWatcher.on 'start' ->
    new Watcher()
```

Then `List.Foo` controller will watch the App event `scroll:bottom` as he like, and supply next page.

There may be other parts interested in this event, for example in Footer view popping a button saying you are at bottom, or another notification saying if you want to see more you need to sign up, etc. They can also listen to the the App vent without need to manage window level DOM, thanks to the beauty of Marionette.

**Important update**
If you watch App vents directly inside controller but not at module level, make sure the controller will stop listen to this vent otherwise the listeners will increase in `App.vents` which is a memory leak.

```
# FooController
onClose: ->
  App.vent.off 'scroll:bottom'
```